# How to use Angular JS tags in Laravel template?

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

As you know Laravel has assets functions in template like as:

```
{{ asset('images/148630374252566.gif')}}
```

When I try to use Angular JS varibles in template Laravel it calls error:

```
{{ currentPlaying.title }}
```

Error:

> Use of undefined constant currentPlaying - assumed 'currentPlaying'
>   (View: \laravel\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your angular interpolation symbol in config of angular module.

```
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
```

And use that in your template.

Please ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Here is the code from Angular doc,

```
<script>
  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
  });


  customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
      this.label = "This binding is brought you by // interpolation symbols.";
  });
</script>
<div ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    //demo.label//
</div>
```

Comment: Where to do this? And how to use after?

Answer (score 2):

how i did it was, in your App.js, just define this;

```
function($interpolateProvider)
{
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
}
```

say i have a `$scope.abcd` in my controller, call it in the blade as such, `<%abcd%>`. hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure this system, otherwise you can't work with angularjs with laravel.
You can see this: https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs